how to add sidebar.additional in search page?
I don't know how to add the sidebar.additional in the search page, can anyone help?
here's what i tried so far in catalogsearch_result_index.xml :
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <attribute name="class" value="page-products"/>
       
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.compare.sidebar"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/sidebar.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="compareProducts" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/compare-products</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        
        <move element="sidebar.additional" destination="columns" />

    </body>
</page>

i basically want the same 3-columns layout that is in the category page: sidebar additional, columns with content and then the sidebar.main with the filters. can anyone help? i can only see the main column and the sidebar main...


Create a Custom Module (if not already created)

Create the necessary directories and files for your custom module:
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/module.xml
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/registration.php
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/module.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="YourVendor_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/registration.php

<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'YourVendor_YourModule',
    __DIR__
);


Define the Layout Update

Create a layout update file to add your custom block to the sidebar.additional section on the search results page:
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your.custom.block" template="YourVendor_YourModule::custom.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>


Create the Template File

Create the template file that will be rendered by your custom block:
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml

<div class="custom-sidebar-block">
    <h3>Custom Sidebar Block</h3>
    <p>This is a custom block added to the sidebar on the search results page.</p>
</div>


Clear Cache and Deploy Static Content

After creating the necessary files, clear the cache and deploy the static content to see the changes:
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f


Try with the code below.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/sidebar.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="compareProducts" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/compare-products</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="columns">
            <container name="div.sidebar.main" label="Sidebar Main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" before="-">
                <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main-content">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="Magento_Catalog::navigation/left.phtml" before="-"/>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="sidebar.main" destination="columns"/>

    </body>
</page>


